# Click Event - Main Document and Dialog jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, click

So on my main page, I have a custom tooltip I built, it's just a div with some information in it that's hidden, and when you select a button it opens the menu. If you click anywhere else in the document, it hides that div. That code looks like this.

```
$(document).on("click", function() {
    $("#supTooltip").fadeOut("fast", "linear");
});
$("#supervisorButton").on("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
});
```

After clicking this, you can click multiple different options in the menu. One brings up a dialog. In that dialog I also have a similar menu for filters. The code looks the same, just different IDs being pulled.

```
$(document).on("click", function() {
    $("#filtersDiv").fadeOut("fast", "linear");
});
$("#filtersButton").on("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
});
```

Can I not do this? I tried to turn off the click event but, it doesn't seem to work. I used this above the second iteration of code.

```
$(document).off("click");
```

Any help would be awesome. I've been racking my brain with this the past couple hours.

**Edit 1:**

jsFiddle was requested. http://jsfiddle.net/yDmAK/1/

That works, however the difference is, menu2 function is not in the same file as menu1 function. The dialog populates data in a separate file using the load event in order to pull from a separate file.

Could that be causing the issue or no?

Comment: You may need a link to a jsfiddle or online example for this.

Comment: I'm still not understanding your exact problem

Comment: Sorry guys, it's not on net, so I'll have to provide a jsfiddle or pictures.

Comment: Provided jsFiddle. Please review the edit, thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use a different method posted by another [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/659025/prc322) on a different thread.

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var container = $("YOUR CONTAINER SELECTOR");

    if (container.has(e.target).length === 0)
    {
        container.hide();
    }
});
```

This seemed to do the trick and is working properly.